# Not able to build UITestCase in project which contain swift package managers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ui-testing, swift-package-manager

I am working on demo code where I have created my own swift packages and which I have imported myself in code.

So project works well after importing the packages. Now I have to write UITestCases for the same, which I am able to write but when I try to build the UITestCases, it gives error for packages.

```
Undefined symbol: SecurityCore.KeychainFramework.unsafeMutableAddressor : SecurityCore.Keychain
```

same for all my packages.
Is there any way to overcome this. I am new to UITestCases. This is my first UITestCase which I am writing.

Any help will be appreciated.
Attaching screen shot of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The missing part for this was, I need to add all the packages in my UITestTarget -> Build Phases -> Link binary files. (attached screen shot)
After adding this, I am able to run the test case for the same.

[image]